# autowired for authentication manager

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I want to implement an authorization and a resource server for Oauth2 and [here](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/springboot-oauth2-client-grant) is my reference site but the private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager gives me an error on intellij like "could not autowire" so how can i fix it?

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("javainuse-client").secret("javainuse-secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials").scopes("resource-server-read", "resource-server-write");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must use an AuthenticationManager (which is not always true, it depends on how you manage users), one will need to be exposed as a bean. Like so:

```
@Configuration
public static class AuthenticationMananagerProvider extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Source (which is an interesting read providing many insights):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11136